# How to get sitemap of webpages?

Tags: web, sitemap

I am trying to analyze some page and to get all necessary information I need to know their web structure ( sitemap - map of web-pages, something like this [Czech pages](https://fit.cvut.cz/sitemap) or [Harvard pages](http://www.harvard.edu/sitemap) )

Is there some **online service** or **program** to which I give **URL** of page and then it display sitemap (I know that there can be link to other pages but if the service would have option to search only to some level it would be great)

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap is often present in a file, located at root of website, and named sitemap.xml.

> eg : http://www.abcdef.com/sitemap.xml

Otherwise, if it is not present, you can try to have a look in a file named robots.txt file (still at root of website)

> It can be defined like that in robots.txt :
>   Sitemap: http://www.abcdef.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of possibilities works. (Give information like this "User-agent: * Disallow: /")

Comment: If you cannot find the sitemap of the website, you'll have to crawl it using a tool like curl.